# Connecting Waterline ORM with Compose MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I can't for the life of me get Sails.js Waterline ORM to connect to a Compose MongoDB. I end up with a `Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?` error message, which is obviously very vague. Has anyone experienced this before? Thanks!

Comment: Show me database connection configuration and what adapter you are using.

Comment: A little bite more information would be helpful; e.g. are you connecting with a mongodb URI?